# How to implement custom junit class loader for class under test?

Tags: java, junit, classloader, junit4

I've a `Version` (interface, abstract class) and a few implementations of it.

Now I'd like to test all the implementations in a single test suit. I suppose that I need to implement a custom class loader that, when asked for a `Version` class, will return a concrete implementation. Which one is chosen can be configured via a system property or env variable.

Or maybe it can be done in a different way? Can anyone tell me how to implement such class loader that will load the class under test based on some external configuration? Or, if it does not make sense can anyone point into the right direction?

Comment: Why not using ServiceLoader (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and testing all implementations in a Parametized test whose data are implementation ?

Comment: I can't do it like that. I need to run all the tests on one particular implementation and then on the next one, and so on.

Comment: I you use maven, you can add several forked test execution with a system property which you can then read.

Comment: @NoDataFound, ok. I can read the property but then I need to load the class based on it. How it can be done?

Comment: `Class.forName(System.getProperty("theProperty")).newInstance()` ?

Comment: `Version` class has no default constructor but that seems, a nice idea. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803381/how-to-implement-custom-junit-class-loader-for-class-under-test?noredirect=1#comment94455935_53803408) comment. Maybe it somehow helps you.

Comment: I also create an instance of `Version` for every single `@Test`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a class loader. Just instantiate the concrete classes. Just because a class is derived from an abstract base class or implements an interface does not forbid you from constructing instances of that class using its constructors.

Comment: Thanks. I knot that it can be done this way. But, unfortunately I cannot use polymorphism.

Comment: @Opal Your comment makes no sense. If to are interested in having several classes that extend an interface or are derived from an abstract base class,  you **are** using polymorphism.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I cannot use it in the way you suggest it. I just can't create all the instances and run the tests iterating over the list of prepared implementations. I just want to substitute the base class with an other implementation depending on some configuration.

Comment: And that is not a good way to write unit tests. A unit test should be straight forward to read and understand. When understanding the test requires to know config files, then you are making that part way too hard.

Comment: @Raedwald, thanks for your input. I've over ten years of experience, know how to implement tests and, trust me, I know what I'm asking about and why. I need this to implement automatic TDD interview task verification, where candidate is asked to implement tests for some part of code and then this set of tests is run with different (somehow spoilt) classes to see whether tests fail where they should and if candidate covered all the requirements. So, as you can see, since I've no control over the test suite I need to some inject the spoilt implementation. Probably, via a class loader.